# How to configure htop to highlight other user names with gray

Tags: htop

Help please figure out how to set **htop** to highlight other user names with gray like dbus user or chrony on the screenshot:

[image]

As for me it works somehow randomly: on one terminals it only shows root user, on other - others user names in gray color (what is desired behavior for me).

Answer (score 0):

htop has hardcoded color scheme and to change it you can only patch source code and build custom htop (see related [issue](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/14))

On other hand, color code that some terminals render as black, others render as dark gray. You can check out if a terminal supports changing color schemes and simply switch black color to suitable.

Check if your terminal has "Use bright colors for bold text" option, it may help as well.

Comment: Thank you for your post, will give a try and post update in case that helped!